# bash find command for directories without permission denied errors

Tags: bash, shell, find, sh

I want to find all files with the name java in folders containing /current/jre/bin/ and without the many permission denied errors.

So I thought `find / -type d '*/current/jre/bin/*' 2>/dev/null` should do the job.
But the return is nothing. I also tried it without the *, with -wholename (with and without *), with an additional -name, -name but without -type d and some other commands.

If I instead search for the java files with `find / -name 'java' 2>/dev/null` I receive eleven path, from which I only need three.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `'*/current/jre/bin/*'` after `-type d` confuses find so it cannot determine which path you want to search.  If you removed the `2>/dev/null` you would see the error `find: paths must precede expression`.

Instead, use a pipe to grep:

```
find / -name 'java' 2>/dev/null | grep '/current/jre/bin/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to say "the path must contain this" is with `-path`

```
find / -type d -path '*/current/jre/bin/*' 2>/dev/null
```

Specifying a bare string in the predicates is an error, which you would easily have found out if you didn't redirect error messages to `/dev/null`.  Even then, having the command return *immediately* even though you are scanning the entire file tree should be a dead giveaway.

Pro tip: also add `-xdev` to the options, to avoid having `find` going into `/dev` and etc.  If you have your files split on multiple partitions, you will then need to specify each partition you want to search in the path list before the predicates.

(The general syntax is `find path1 path2 path3 ... -list -of -predicates`.)